# SQL Combining rows, under assumptions short as possible

Tags: sql, row, aggregation

I have a database SQL with columns A, B, C and D.
For each row the 4 cases are occuring:

```
>     A  B  C  D     

>     X  Y  -  -
>     Y  -  Z  W
>     R  -  T  -
>     S  -  -  P
```

I want the Output to be:

```
>     A  B  C  D    

>     X  Y  Z  W
```

So whenever there exist an X to Y and Y has an element in C or D (or both), 
than keep y and add all of the elements in one row. else rows should not be in the output.

somehow I thought of Group By but nothing works out.

Thank you for you help :)

Comment: Self join it on B

Comment: could you explain your answer please?

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want:

```
select tx.a, tx.b, ty.c, ty.d
from t tx join
     t ty
     on tx.a = 'X' and ty.a = 'Y'
```

Comment: I don't understand.. what is t and what is ty.a?

Comment: @P.Rot . . . Those are table aliases and an important part of the SQL language.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of

```
create table t (
    A varchar(2) not null,
    B varchar(2),
    C varchar(2),
    D varchar(2)
); 

insert t(A,B,C,D)
values
     ('X','Y',null,null)
    ,('Y',null,'Z','W')
    ,('R',null,'T',null)
    ,('S',null,null,'P');

select t1.A, t1.B, t2.C, t2.D
from t t1
join t t2 on t1.B = t2.A 
         and coalesce (t2.C, t2.D) is not null;
```

Comment: and t2.C is not null 
         and t2.D is not null                     Something is wrong for me here... it might be that D or C can be empty... but not both. The "and" gives me empty table. So I want an output giving me X and Y if C is empty or D is empty and leave column out if C and D is empty

Comment: @P.Rot .. it can be done with `coalesce`, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

With a self join:

```
SELECT t.A, t.B, tt.C, tt.D
FROM tablename t INNER JOIN tablename tt 
ON tt.A = t.B AND COALESCE(tt.C, tt.D) IS NOT NULL;
```

Without `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT t.A, t.B, tt.C, tt.D
FROM tablename t INNER JOIN tablename tt 
ON tt.A = t.B AND (tt.C IS NOT NULL OR tt.D IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Please only with Joins and Logicals (AND, OR) not with a function like coalesce

Comment: Thank this is the perfect answer to me :)

Comment: If this answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark at the left.